# Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK] on increasing minsdk version to 18 from 14

Tags: android

I am working on upgrading an app and need to use android minsdk version 18 for the purpose. At present my minsdk version is 14 and targetsdk version is 22. The code compiles with minsdk version 18 and targetsdk version 22 but when I try to install the app on a device where it was previously installed I am getting this error. **Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK]**

How can I re-install the app on the system after changing my minsdk version from 14 to 18.

Comment: Did you uninstall the previous version manually before?

Comment: What android-version is running on the device?